# No Body received when requesting JSON

Tags: json, http, go

I'm trying to download a json file from https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/

It works perfectly fine in postman, or the browser and i get a JSON object, but when i try in golang with either my own program or the postman example the request body is empty. I can see that it was a 200 response but no body.

Any pointers as to why it's working in postman, but not in the golang snippet?

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

type dataobject struct {
    Events []struct {
        ID                     int       `json:"id"`
        Name                   string    `json:"name"`
        DeadlineTime           time.Time `json:"deadline_time"`
        AverageEntryScore      int       `json:"average_entry_score"`
        Finished               bool      `json:"finished"`
        DataChecked            bool      `json:"data_checked"`
        HighestScoringEntry    int       `json:"highest_scoring_entry"`
        DeadlineTimeEpoch      int       `json:"deadline_time_epoch"`
        DeadlineTimeGameOffset int       `json:"deadline_time_game_offset"`
        HighestScore           int       `json:"highest_score"`
        IsPrevious             bool      `json:"is_previous"`
        IsCurrent              bool      `json:"is_current"`
        IsNext                 bool      `json:"is_next"`
        ChipPlays              []struct {
            ChipName  string `json:"chip_name"`
            NumPlayed int    `json:"num_played"`
        } `json:"chip_plays"`
        MostSelected      int `json:"most_selected"`
        MostTransferredIn int `json:"most_transferred_in"`
        TopElement        int `json:"top_element"`
        TopElementInfo    struct {
            ID     int `json:"id"`
            Points int `json:"points"`
        } `json:"top_element_info"`
        TransfersMade     int `json:"transfers_made"`
        MostCaptained     int `json:"most_captained"`
        MostViceCaptained int `json:"most_vice_captained"`
    } `json:"events"`
    GameSettings struct {
        LeagueJoinPrivateMax         int           `json:"league_join_private_max"`
        LeagueJoinPublicMax          int           `json:"league_join_public_max"`
        LeagueMaxSizePublicClassic   int           `json:"league_max_size_public_classic"`
        LeagueMaxSizePublicH2H       int           `json:"league_max_size_public_h2h"`
        LeagueMaxSizePrivateH2H      int           `json:"league_max_size_private_h2h"`
        LeagueMaxKoRoundsPrivateH2H  int           `json:"league_max_ko_rounds_private_h2h"`
        LeaguePrefixPublic           string        `json:"league_prefix_public"`
        LeaguePointsH2HWin           int           `json:"league_points_h2h_win"`
        LeaguePointsH2HLose          int           `json:"league_points_h2h_lose"`
        LeaguePointsH2HDraw          int           `json:"league_points_h2h_draw"`
        LeagueKoFirstInsteadOfRandom bool          `json:"league_ko_first_instead_of_random"`
        CupStartEventID              int           `json:"cup_start_event_id"`
        CupStopEventID               int           `json:"cup_stop_event_id"`
        CupQualifyingMethod          string        `json:"cup_qualifying_method"`
        CupType                      string        `json:"cup_type"`
        SquadSquadplay               int           `json:"squad_squadplay"`
        SquadSquadsize               int           `json:"squad_squadsize"`
        SquadTeamLimit               int           `json:"squad_team_limit"`
        SquadTotalSpend              int           `json:"squad_total_spend"`
        UICurrencyMultiplier         int           `json:"ui_currency_multiplier"`
        UIUseSpecialShirts           bool          `json:"ui_use_special_shirts"`
        UISpecialShirtExclusions     []interface{} `json:"ui_special_shirt_exclusions"`
        StatsFormDays                int           `json:"stats_form_days"`
        SysViceCaptainEnabled        bool          `json:"sys_vice_captain_enabled"`
        TransfersCap                 int           `json:"transfers_cap"`
        TransfersSellOnFee           float64       `json:"transfers_sell_on_fee"`
        LeagueH2HTiebreakStats       []string      `json:"league_h2h_tiebreak_stats"`
        Timezone                     string        `json:"timezone"`
    } `json:"game_settings"`
    Phases []struct {
        ID         int    `json:"id"`
        Name       string `json:"name"`
        StartEvent int    `json:"start_event"`
        StopEvent  int    `json:"stop_event"`
    } `json:"phases"`
    Teams []struct {
        Code                int         `json:"code"`
        Draw                int         `json:"draw"`
        Form                interface{} `json:"form"`
        ID                  int         `json:"id"`
        Loss                int         `json:"loss"`
        Name                string      `json:"name"`
        Played              int         `json:"played"`
        Points              int         `json:"points"`
        Position            int         `json:"position"`
        ShortName           string      `json:"short_name"`
        Strength            int         `json:"strength"`
        TeamDivision        interface{} `json:"team_division"`
        Unavailable         bool        `json:"unavailable"`
        Win                 int         `json:"win"`
        StrengthOverallHome int         `json:"strength_overall_home"`
        StrengthOverallAway int         `json:"strength_overall_away"`
        StrengthAttackHome  int         `json:"strength_attack_home"`
        StrengthAttackAway  int         `json:"strength_attack_away"`
        StrengthDefenceHome int         `json:"strength_defence_home"`
        StrengthDefenceAway int         `json:"strength_defence_away"`
        PulseID             int         `json:"pulse_id"`
    } `json:"teams"`
    TotalPlayers int `json:"total_players"`
    Elements     []struct {
        ChanceOfPlayingNextRound         interface{} `json:"chance_of_playing_next_round"`
        ChanceOfPlayingThisRound         interface{} `json:"chance_of_playing_this_round"`
        Code                             int         `json:"code"`
        CostChangeEvent                  int         `json:"cost_change_event"`
        CostChangeEventFall              int         `json:"cost_change_event_fall"`
        CostChangeStart                  int         `json:"cost_change_start"`
        CostChangeStartFall              int         `json:"cost_change_start_fall"`
        DreamteamCount                   int         `json:"dreamteam_count"`
        ElementType                      int         `json:"element_type"`
        EpNext                           string      `json:"ep_next"`
        EpThis                           string      `json:"ep_this"`
        EventPoints                      int         `json:"event_points"`
        FirstName                        string      `json:"first_name"`
        Form                             string      `json:"form"`
        ID                               int         `json:"id"`
        InDreamteam                      bool        `json:"in_dreamteam"`
        News                             string      `json:"news"`
        NewsAdded                        interface{} `json:"news_added"`
        NowCost                          int         `json:"now_cost"`
        Photo                            string      `json:"photo"`
        PointsPerGame                    string      `json:"points_per_game"`
        SecondName                       string      `json:"second_name"`
        SelectedByPercent                string      `json:"selected_by_percent"`
        Special                          bool        `json:"special"`
        SquadNumber                      interface{} `json:"squad_number"`
        Status                           string      `json:"status"`
        Team                             int         `json:"team"`
        TeamCode                         int         `json:"team_code"`
        TotalPoints                      int         `json:"total_points"`
        TransfersIn                      int         `json:"transfers_in"`
        TransfersInEvent                 int         `json:"transfers_in_event"`
        TransfersOut                     int         `json:"transfers_out"`
        TransfersOutEvent                int         `json:"transfers_out_event"`
        ValueForm                        string      `json:"value_form"`
        ValueSeason                      string      `json:"value_season"`
        WebName                          string      `json:"web_name"`
        Minutes                          int         `json:"minutes"`
        GoalsScored                      int         `json:"goals_scored"`
        Assists                          int         `json:"assists"`
        CleanSheets                      int         `json:"clean_sheets"`
        GoalsConceded                    int         `json:"goals_conceded"`
        OwnGoals                         int         `json:"own_goals"`
        PenaltiesSaved                   int         `json:"penalties_saved"`
        PenaltiesMissed                  int         `json:"penalties_missed"`
        YellowCards                      int         `json:"yellow_cards"`
        RedCards                         int         `json:"red_cards"`
        Saves                            int         `json:"saves"`
        Bonus                            int         `json:"bonus"`
        Bps                              int         `json:"bps"`
        Influence                        string      `json:"influence"`
        Creativity                       string      `json:"creativity"`
        Threat                           string      `json:"threat"`
        IctIndex                         string      `json:"ict_index"`
        InfluenceRank                    int         `json:"influence_rank"`
        InfluenceRankType                int         `json:"influence_rank_type"`
        CreativityRank                   int         `json:"creativity_rank"`
        CreativityRankType               int         `json:"creativity_rank_type"`
        ThreatRank                       int         `json:"threat_rank"`
        ThreatRankType                   int         `json:"threat_rank_type"`
        IctIndexRank                     int         `json:"ict_index_rank"`
        IctIndexRankType                 int         `json:"ict_index_rank_type"`
        CornersAndIndirectFreekicksOrder interface{} `json:"corners_and_indirect_freekicks_order"`
        CornersAndIndirectFreekicksText  string      `json:"corners_and_indirect_freekicks_text"`
        DirectFreekicksOrder             interface{} `json:"direct_freekicks_order"`
        DirectFreekicksText              string      `json:"direct_freekicks_text"`
        PenaltiesOrder                   interface{} `json:"penalties_order"`
        PenaltiesText                    string      `json:"penalties_text"`
    } `json:"elements"`
    ElementStats []struct {
        Label string `json:"label"`
        Name  string `json:"name"`
    } `json:"element_stats"`
    ElementTypes []struct {
        ID                 int    `json:"id"`
        PluralName         string `json:"plural_name"`
        PluralNameShort    string `json:"plural_name_short"`
        SingularName       string `json:"singular_name"`
        SingularNameShort  string `json:"singular_name_short"`
        SquadSelect        int    `json:"squad_select"`
        SquadMinPlay       int    `json:"squad_min_play"`
        SquadMaxPlay       int    `json:"squad_max_play"`
        UIShirtSpecific    bool   `json:"ui_shirt_specific"`
        SubPositionsLocked []int  `json:"sub_positions_locked"`
        ElementCount       int    `json:"element_count"`
    } `json:"element_types"`
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Starting EDL-Draft")

    url := "https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/"
    method := "GET"

    client := &http.Client {
    }
    req, err := http.NewRequest(method, url, nil)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    res, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(string(body))

    var result dataobject
    if err := json.Unmarshal(body, &result); err != nil {  
        fmt.Println("Can not unmarshal JSON")
    }

    fmt.Println("Finishing EPL-Draft")
}
```

[image: Screen Shot from Postman working]

Comment: When I `curl https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/` I also get a 200 response and empty body.

Comment: What is postman doing differently then from the snippet to get a body response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a `User-Agent` request header: `req.Header.Set("User-Agent", "xxx")`

Without seeing the docs, I'm not sure why this is, but any arbitrary value seems to do.

Comment: Perfect. Problem solved thank you!